# Переписать код с Python на C++

Tags: python, c++, строки, ввод

Пожалуйста, помогите переписать код с Python на C++
Программа должна выводить самое частое слово в тесте
на вход даётся число строк, затем вводятся сами строки:

```
txt={}
m=0
for _ in range(int(input())):
    for word in input().split():
        if word in txt:
            txt[word]+=1
        else:
            txt[word]=1
        if txt[word]>m:
            m=txt[word]
for k,val in sorted(txt.items()):
    if val==m:
        print(k)
```

тест:

```
3  
vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg vqcg  
vqcg vqcg  
vqcg
```

Пытался сам сделать через `map`, но ничего не получается

К сожалению, это максимум что у меня получилось:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;
main()
{
    int n, k, i;
    string s, a[100];
    cin >> n;
    getline(cin, s);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) getline(cin, a[i]);

    istringstream ist(s);
    map<string, int> m;

    for(string word; ist >> word; ++m[word]);

    cout << m.begin()->first << endl;
}
```

Comment: Так вы бы привели свои попытки - это бы вызвало куда больший интерес и меньшее желание поставить минус вопросу... Одно дело - смотрите, я хочу сделать такую программу, вот мои попытки, должно быть так, но работает вот так, помогите. И другое - я тут нашел код на Питоне, мне надо сдать на С++, я что-то там написал (а вдруг поверят?), но не вышло - так напишите домашку за меня! Видите разницу?

Comment: К сожалению, это максимум что у меня получилось
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
main(){
 int n,k,i;
 string s,a[100];
 cin>>n;
 getline (cin,s);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++) getline (cin,a[i]);
 istringstream ist(s);
 map<string,int> m;
 for (string word; ist >> word; ++m[word] );
    cout << m.begin()->first<<endl;

}
выводит слово, начинающиеся с первой по алфавиту буквы, даже если оно не самое частое

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос, отредактировав его

Answer (score 3):

Сравните этот код со своим и попробуйте разобраться, в чем у вас проблемы, самостоятельно (я постарался минимально изменять ваш код и ваш подход):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    map<string, int> m;
    int n;
    string s;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        getline(cin, s);
        istringstream ist(s);
        for(string word; ist >> word; ++m[word]);
    }
    cout << max_element(m.begin(),m.end(),
                [](auto a, auto b) { return a.second < b.second; })->first
         << endl;
}
```

Comment: что то не то вы выводите

Comment: @Maggot А, да, по жаре на вывод и не глянул :) Все равно у ТС в строке единственное слово :)

Comment: у нас дождь )))

Answer (score 1):

Да составте частоту включений через std::map и найдите в ней максимальныйое значение приавязанное к ключу

```
Пример логики - 

std::map<std::string, int> m;
  
  // TODO : add dump line from stdin

  std::string s{"test line test line test 1"};
  std::istringstream ist(s);
  for(std::string word; ist >> word; ++m[word]);

  auto f{[] (const std::pair<std::string, int>& p1, const std::pair<std::string, int>& p2) {return p1.second < p2.second;}};
  auto p_i = std::max_element(std::begin(m), std::end(m), f);

  std::cout << "max frenq : " << p_i->first << std::endl;
```

Comment: А что такое "составте гисту"? Гиста - это гистограмма? Если да, то где она нарисована у вас? :)

Comment: @dIm0n вот нашли до чего придраться

Comment: Не, ну если считаете, что я придераюсь, то ваш код вообще не обязан компилироваться, потому что не определены хедеры `<utility>` и `<algorithm>`. Не компилит clang https://godbolt.org/z/GGG9Gx, не компилит gcc https://godbolt.org/z/x9fM9r

Comment: @dIm0n gcc10 проблем нет + я не использую веб ide. Т.к не доверяю им

Comment: Я что обманываю вас? :) Откройте ссылку, там gcc 10.1

Comment: @dIm0n перебрал - проблем нет - если ваш компилятор их требует - указывайте

Comment: Что значит "перебрал"? У вас неправильное отношение: вы даёте ответ, а значит ответ должен работать не только у вас, но и у читающих. Если не хотите добавлять, то хотя бы укажите, что программа непортабельна, но работает у вас для определенного компилятора с определёнными ключами, чтобы ТС и читающие знали, как запустить ваш код, чтобы он работал

Comment: @dIm0n это примерный вариант решения и нет пометки что он работает на любом env - я могу просто оставить код без Майна и заголовков

Comment: Ну теперь, когда вы сделали правку, да :) А до этого по умолчанию подразумевался корректный C++ код

Comment: @dIm0n  договорились